# Windows Form GUI isn't being shown while it is running code

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In between 2 forms, I am running some code, which takes about 9 seconds.
To let the user see, what is going on, I have created an extra form with some progressbars.

The idea is, that they click a button on Form A, that they see the Form B with the progressbars, and that this immediately goes to Form C when it is ready.

This is working, but I only see Form B when it is finished, and not while it is working and updating the progressbars.  Most likely since my code never leaves the Load()

```
    Private Sub frmLoadScreen_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lblMelding.Visible = False
    GetData() 
    PhrasesErrorControl() 

    Dim frmerrorproducts As New frmProductsErrorControl
    frmerrorproducts.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

[image: Form B]

If I would add an extra button on Form B, then it works like it should be, and I see everything from scratch.  But I want to have it automatically of course.

Comment: If you move that code to the `Shown` event, does it work better? You could run a Task, but it's probably redundant here (a ProgressBar can update also in a close loop, it refreshes itself constantly, the Labels may require a *manual* refresh).

Comment: You are doing the work before the form finishes loading (which cannot be sooner than it returns from the Load handler). No wonder you cannot see it.

Comment: You might benefit from [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567). In that case, `frmProductsErrorControl` would display `frmLoadScreen` instead of the other way around.

Comment: Of course... the Shown is the easiest solution.